# Enumerate contents of specific folder DotNetZip, without child folders

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

Using Ionic.Zip

I wish to display the files or folders in a specific folder. I am using the SelectEntries method, but it unfortunately is filtering out the folders. Not what I was expecting using '*'.

```
ICollection<ZipEntry> selectEntries = _zipFile.SelectEntries("*",rootLocation)
```

If I follow an alternative approach:

```
IEnumerable<ZipEntry> selectEntries = _zipFile.Entries.Where(e => e.FileName.StartsWith(rootLocation))
```

I face two problems:

1. I have to switch '/' for '\' potentially.
2. I get all the subfolders.

Which is not desirable.

Anyone know why SelectEntries returns no folders, or am I misusing it?

Comment: I notice _zipFile.Entries.Where(e=>e.IsDirectory) also returns no entries it's as if the are no folders but viewing in explorer shows a folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in my particular case. I think something about the way the Zipfile was constructed led to it appearing to have folders but none actually existed i.e. the following code yielded an empty list.

```
_zipFile.Entries.Where(e=>e.IsDirectory).AsList();  // always empty!
```

I used the following snippet to achieve what I needed. The regex is not as comprehensive as it should be but worked for all cases I needed.

```
var conformedRootLocation = rootLocation.Replace('\\','/').TrimEnd('/') + "/";
var pattern = string.Format(@"({0})([a-z|A-Z|.|_|0-9|\s]+)/?", conformedRootLocation);
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
return _zipFile.EntryFileNames.Select(e => regex.Match(e))
        .Where(match => match.Success)
        .Select(match => match.Groups[2].Value)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(f => new DirectoryResource
        {
            Name = f, IsDirectory = !Path.HasExtension(f)
        })
        .ToList();
```